# How to check spam in content with bbcode markup?

Tags: php, preg-replace, spam-prevention

I am using as a bbcode:

```
$text=preg_replace("/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/i","<b>\\1</b>", $text);
```

But some ppl doing spam with this bb code like this:

```
[b]ww[/b][b]w[/b].[b]ex[/b][b][/b][b]um[/b].[b]c[/b][b]o[/b][b]m[/b]
```

I have mysql database storing this spam keyword. But it won't catch this link, because they use bbcode. How can I check if the contents is spam when it has bbcode markup?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest removing the bbcode and checking for the full word.

Also, you might want to use [Akismet](http://akismet.com) to verify that posts are not spam. PEAR has a [Akismet package](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_Akismet2) which makes interfacing the service very easy.

Answer (score 0):

If it is OK for you to block whole post/comment if it has spam keyword, then you can do this approach (sorry, no code here):

1) remove all bb codes and other formatting (e.g. html, if present)

2) work with plain text